# Difference between pip install cudatoolkit=9.0 and download install from CUDA website

Tags: cuda

I have a simple confusion, what is difference between `pip install cudatoolkit=9.0` and download the run file from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive and install cuda 9.0.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

The `.run` file, is delegated to install the CUDA drivers for you GPU in your system. Then, after that you have the driver installed, you can use the `cudatoolkit` in order to wrap the low level C/C++ function in python language. Before the installation of the python toolkit, you need to be sure that the drivers are correctly installed.

More info about the procedure: https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python